# Changing Sparkline color based on another cell's value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sparklines

[image]

I have a `sparkline` that shows how complete an event is.  I would like the color to change based on the value in another cell.

- If the value is less than 50, I want it to be red;
- If the value is greater than 51, but less than 75, I want it to be yellow; and - If the value is greater than 76, I want it to be green.

What would be the syntax for that?

I've tried nested if statements, but receive the message that only 3 arguments are allowed.

This is the formula I've tried:

```
=SPARKLINE((COUNTIF(H4:H14,"yes")/counta(H4:H14)*100),{"charttype","bar";"color1",if(E2<50, "red",if(E2>51, but E2<75, "yellow",if(E2>76, "green")));"max",100})
```

Comment: I updated my post with the info you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SPARKLINE((COUNTIF(H4:H14,"yes")/COUNTA(H4:H14)*100),
 {"charttype", "bar";
  "color1",    IF(E2>76, "green", 
               IF(E2>51, "yellow", "red"));
  "max",       100})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I tried adding that formula, but the Sparkline is green even though the value is 45 and it should be red. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: either format of cell **E2** needs to be "Number" or change `E2` to `VALUE(E2)`